# Getting the record id of a model just saved to the database MVC4 ASP.Net

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Using ASP.Net/C# with MVC4 and EF 5.  I have a base model in which several other models are linked to via the id.  For example

```
 public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Created { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Submitted { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Finalized { get; set; }

        public string UserProfileSite { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Demographic> Demographics { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Demographic> Demographics { get; set; }
     }
```

The Demographics have a foreign key with the personId.  When they add a person they get sent to fill out the demographics information.  However since the demographics have a foriegn key of personId I need to create the person record.

I can create the person before going to the demographics view as follows:

```
Person person = new Person();
person.UserId = curuser.UserId;
person.UserProfileSite = curuser.Site;
person.Created = DateTime.Now;
db.Persons.Add(person);
db.SaveChanges();
```

How do I get the personId of the record I just saved to the database so I can pass it to my Demographics so the model has the foreign key of personId?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming you have not turned of changeTracking within entity framework, you should be able to simply get the id of the object after you save it to the database

```
Person person = new Person();
person.UserId = curuser.UserId;
person.UserProfileSite = curuser.Site;
person.Created = DateTime.Now;
db.Persons.Add(person);
db.SaveChanges();
var personId = person.Id;
```